# what's the meaning of request.headers.setdefault() in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

I wanna set custom `UserAgentMiddleware` with scrapy. But I don't know the action of `request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)` when I saw it, and I didn't find the method both document of scrapy and requests.

Where can I find the any explanation about it?

Comment: it is method in standard python dictionary - see [dictionary setdefault](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`headers` is a normal dictionary, so `setdefault` would be a way to set a value to that dictionary **if that value isn't present there** already.

The explanation would be that the Middleware sets the User-Agent **by defaut** only if you didn't set one already on the spider process.

You can set something like this in your spider code:

```
...
request.headers['User-Agent'] = 'My Custom User Agent'
yield request
```

meaning that when that code reaches the Middleware, the user-agent won't be overridden or changed.

The other Middlewares (or any other process) that comes before this one, could also modify the `User-Agent`, and it won't be changed by this code, because it respects the ones previously set.