# Scrapy - LinkExtractor & setting DEPTH_LIMIT not working?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I am passing in a `start_url` that is a page of news articles(ex. [cnn.com](https://www.cnn.com/specials/last-50-stories)). But, I just want to extract the news article itself, I don't want to follow any links on article page. To do that, I'm using a [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider) with the following rule:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('regexToMatchArticleUrls',),
    deny=('someDenyUrls')), callback='parse_article_page'),
)

def parse_article_page(self,response): 
    #extracts the title, date, body, etc of article
```

I've enabled the [`scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware) and set [`DEPTH_LIMIT = 1`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DEPTH_LIMIT).

However, I'm still getting links crawled from the individual article pages that happen to match the `regexToMatchArticleUrls`, as they are links to other parts of the same website (and I cannot make the regex more restrictive).

But, why are these links getting crawled at all when the `DEPTH_LIMIT=1`? Is it because the `DEPTH_LIMIT` resets for each link extracted from `LinkExtractor`, ie. the article page urls? Is there a way either to make `DEPTH_LIMIT` work or extend the `DepthMiddleware` to not crawl links on the article page? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the DepthMiddleware to work correctly the meta attribute needs to be passed from one request to another, otherwise, `depth` will be set to 0 after each new request.

Unfortunaly, by default, the CrawlSpider doesn't keep this meta attribute from one requests to the next.

This can be solved by using spider middlewares (`middlewares.py`):

```
from scrapy import Request


class StickyDepthSpiderMiddleware:

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        key_found = response.meta.get('depth', None)
        for x in result:
            if isinstance(x, Request) and key_found is not None:
                x.meta.setdefault('depth', key_found)
            yield x
```

Also, don't forget to include this middleware on your `settings.py`:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = { '{your_project_name}.middlewares.StickyDepthSpiderMiddleware' : 100 }
```

Comment: Ohh I see..thank you! But what does `self.key` refer to here?

Comment: I also tried `x.meta.setdefault('depth', key_found)` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050573/whats-the-meaning-of-request-headers-setdefault-in-scrapy) and I'm not sure why that doesn't work?

Comment: Hello, `self.key` should be `depth`, my bad. Could you paste your log run to see what could be happening?